# starting python script at startup

Tags: python-3.x, camera, reboot

I serched and tried different ways to start a python script which starts the camera on a raspberry PI3.

**first attempt** : through crontab

1. `sudo crontab -e`
   added : `@reboot python3 /home/pi/camera.py`
2. script :
   `from picamera import PiCamera
   from time import sleep
   camera = PiCamera()
   camera.framerate = 15
   camera.start_preview()`

**second attempt** through crontab :

1. `sudo crontab -e`
   added : `@reboot /home/pi/launcher.sh >/home/pi/log/cameralog.log 2>&1`
2. script camera.py stays thesame
3. launcher.sh :
   `#!/bin/bash
   clear
   cd /
   cd home/pi
   /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/camera.py
   cd /`

**third attempt** :
removed all from crontab and used rc.local
`sudo nano /etc/rc.local`
added : `/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/camera.py&`

Non of the above ways is starting the script at reboot.

I'm new to raspberry and python.
what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Type-

```
sudo nano /etc/profile
```

at the end of the file add the following line

```
sudo python2 (or 3) yourfile.py
```